# Is it safe to pipe multiple commands output to the same file simultaneously using tee?

Tags: bash, pipe, tee

I am piping the output from multiple commands into the same file simultaneously using terminal like this:

```bsh
cmd1 | tee -a /tmp/file
```

```bsh
cmd2 | tee -a /tmp/file
```

```bsh
cmd3 | tee -a /tmp/file
```

Is it safe to use? Any data loss or read/write permission problem with this method?

**Edit**: I am fine with output getting intermixed, I just want to make sure that everything get written to the file. What if two commands tries to write the output to the file exactly same time, Will it crash or not?

Comment: Assuming these commands run in parallel, it is not safe.

Comment: To prevent data loss you can use the "append" (`-a`) option of `tee`, but this will not guarantee that the outputs will not be garbled (=not intermixed) in the output file.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli , Yes these commands run in parallel. I missed to add `-a` option in the question. i have edited the question now, please check edit.

Comment: I think there is a possibility that you can lose data. See also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842511

Comment: I would prefer something like: `{ cmd1 & cmd2 & cmd3 & } | tee /tmp/file`. I think that this version will never lose data..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use tee with `append` (`-a`) mode, then there's no risk of data loss, with the exception of filesystems that don't have an append operation (e.g., NFS).  In `append` mode, `tee` opens the file with the `O_APPEND` flag.

```
$ echo 1 | strace tee -a /tmp/file 2>&1 | grep open | grep /tmp/file
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/file", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0666) = 3
```

From `man 2 openat`:

> ```
> O_APPEND
>      The file is opened in append mode.  Before each write(2), the
>      file offset is positioned at the end of the file, as if with
>      lseek(2).  The modification of the file offset and the write
>      operation are performed as a single atomic step.
> ```

The key sentence there is *The modification of the file offset and the write operation are performed as a single atomic step*.  Every call to `write()` from whichever instance of `tee` is guaranteed to atomically position the file offset to the end of the file, then write the data.

The `openat` man page does note that this pattern of use is not safe on NFS filesystems (as I mentioned earlier):

> ```
>      O_APPEND may lead to corrupted files on NFS filesystems if more
>      than one process appends data to a file at once.  This is be‐
>      cause  NFS does not support appending to a file, so the client
>      kernel has to simulate it, which can't be done without a race
>      condition.
> ```